# How to display RegEx pattern for parameters in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, http, swagger, swagger-ui, endpoint

I am creating an API with a HTTP endpoint where there is a RegEx restriction on the parameter `myDateInput`. I use the default `WeatherForecastController` to illustrate, reduced to only the necessary parts for this example.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SplunkStatRelayService.Web.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public WeatherForecast Get(
        [FromQuery, RegularExpression("^(\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d)"), Description("myDateInput must match the pattern")]
        string myDateInput)
    {
        return new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.Parse(myDateInput),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = myDateInput,
        };
    }
}
```

The RegEx works, and if I try to input something that doesn't match the pattern I get this response, as intended.

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-8f9e4856bc5bfe091965e0404d28f9e9-8791bdf5988a2ec2-00",
    "errors": {
        "myDateInput": ["The field myDateInput must match the regular expression '^(\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d)'."]
    }
}
```

However, in Swagger UI, all you can see is that `myDateInput` is a string, like you can see in the image under. So, a user of my API will not know the required pattern until he attempts a request and receives the error from above.

[image]

How can I make the RegEx pattern be visible in Swagger UI? Same goes for the Description in my code above, which does not appear anywhere at the moment. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

The answer to this question ([Swagger / Swashbuckle string property options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301067/swagger-swashbuckle-string-property-options)) seems to achieve what I want, but I don't understand what I am missing, as he seems to just use `[RegularExpression]` like me. Only thing is he mentions  a file "swagger.json". I don't have this file in my project. Do I need to manually create this "swagger.json" to get the documentation I want? Or is it supposed to be automatically generated?

I found somewhere that I need to add `EnableAnnotations` in `services.AddSwaggerGen` in my Startup file, like so, but that didn't change anything.:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.EnableAnnotations());
```

Answer (score 0):

You already used the `Description`attribute on the parameter. Normally this text will be added as a parameter description. Here is an example:

```
[HttpGet("Foo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo([Description("Bar")] string myDateInput)
{
    return Ok(myDateInput);
}
```

[image: Swagger parameter description]

So, there seems to be something *other* wrong in your system, why this approach doesn't work. As you can see in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/768), the problem has already been solved years ago, so I would guess you're not using an older version, that doesn't support this.

Maybe you should setup a fresh new project and test if it works there and then try to find out the differences to your current project.

Comment: Hm. I created a brand new project: ASP.Net Core, Web API, SDK 7.0, Framework net7.0. I copy pasted your "Foo" "Bar" example into this new project. `GET /WeatherForecast/Foo` shows up as an endpoint in Swagger UI, but it does *not* show "Bar" in the description like it does for you. It looks just like in my previous example. You didn't do anything else but this?

Comment: I tested it in my current project, where it already is in use. After checking the setup I'm using NSwag.AspNetCore, Version=13.19.0.0 and call the extension methods `.UseOpenApi()` and `.UseSwaggerUI3()` on the `IApplicationBuilder app` instance.

Comment: Also in the Swagger UI website you can see in the top left a link to the generated and used swagger.json file. When you click on it, you can take a look at that json file. Check if the comment is within that file to find out if it is a problem of the swagger generator or the UI visualization.